# angularjs - localstorage not loading properly

Tags: angularjs, rootscope, angular-local-storage

I'm working on a little web app for a school project, I store user data on localstorage like this:

```
UserService.login($scope.user).then(function (response){
    if(response.data.Error){
        $scope.credentialsError = true;
    }else{
        $rootScope.cliente = response.data.result;
        localStorageService.set('cliente', $rootScope.cliente);
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }
});
```

As long as I remain in the page, everything works fine, the user is still in $rootScope doing it's thing. The problem comes when I reload.
Upon startup i run this:

```
angular.module('app-gp').run([
  "$rootScope",  "localStorageService", "$state", function($state,localStorageService, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.cliente = localStorageService.get('cliente');
}]);
```

Which appears to correctly get the user data from local storage. However when I request $rootScope.cliente from a controller or a template I get undefined.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i managed to solve the problem.
It seems it was never about the localStorageservice, what i did was rearrange this:

```
angular.module('app-gp').run(["$rootScope", "localStorageService", "$state", function($rootScope, localStorageService, $state) {
```

and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the localStorageService is functioning properly. I am not sure about the implementation of localStorageService, but be aware that the localStorage only supports string values, and you will have to convert response.data.result to string. In chrome, you can use developer tools->Resources tab and look at the "Local Storage" and see whether the storage is actually happening.

Ideally I would have posted this as a comment, but don't have sufficient reputation on this site to do that as yet..

Comment: It is working, I'm currently using [this local storage service](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) and when i run the page I log `$rootScope.cliente = localStorageService.get('cliente');
  console.log($rootScope.cliente);` and it is the object I need. However, I get undefined when i call the object from my templates

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine However the implementation of local storage service might be problematical.
You should use the well known ngStorage service for this job.
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage